# TFS branching : manage small development

Tags: tfs, branch

I have a question about how manage branch and small development ?

Currently, we are using a branch by feature but in some cases, we have small development which need  one or two days of developments ?

What is the solution ? Create a temporary branch ? Do cherry picking ?

And for the answer "Read the tfs branching guide", I have already read this documents.

Thanks and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why create branch at all? Is this a place to "Test" the changes before integration into Main? Can you just code straight into Main and test there?

If this is not possible, then create a branch for the Work, do the work there, keep Forward Integration merging Main into this Work branch. When the change is ready for release, Reverse Integration merge the Work branch back into Main. You can then delete the Work branch and any builds associated with it. This will still show the changesets when viewing the file's history in Main.

Comment: The branching structure could change if there is a better solution. For the first solution which structure do you propose ? I've already think about the second solution who seems to be the better. Indeed small development are frequent and we need to release frequently.

Comment: This is becoming overly broad for SO, but it sounds like adopting a scrum methodology would work well for you.

Answer (score 0):

For a small development you’d be better off with creating a new label in existing branch rather than branching just to add one small feature.